# Find duplicate rows violating unique constraint

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

```
mysql> select user_id, content_type_id, object_id, count(*) as num 
from vote_vote group by user_id, content_type_id, object_id 
having num > 1;

+----------+-----------------+-----------+-----+
| user_id  | content_type_id | object_id | num |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+-----+
| 25754992 |             961 |   3665767 |   2 |
| 38896810 |             961 |   3733660 |   3 |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+-----+
```

The unique key is show in "show create table"

```
UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`content_type_id`,`object_id`),
```

My Question:
How can this be happened? **Why the unique key does not work** on these records?

Some more strange results:

[image]

`show create table` output:

[image]

Comment: You're sure you have several rows with the same unique key?? It shouldn't be allowed by the db server unless you use the IGNORE key word in your insert or update statement..

Comment: Are you asking us for a way to _find_ duplicate rows, or are you saying that you _found_ duplicate rows and you want clarification?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated my question, Do you have some clues?

Comment: @Jorge that is not what IGNORE means